# How to change the edge of Shapes.Path to rounded from flat?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, path, shapes

I have a Shapes.Path that I filled with a binding like this:

```
<Path Stroke=Black"
      Opacity="0.5"
      StrokeThickness="10"
      Data="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</Path>
```

The edges of this path are flat.
I would like to change this to a rounded edge.

I played around with

```
<Style x:Key="PathStyle" TargetType="Path">
```

but I can't find a property which would allow me to do what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `StrokeLineJoin` property to `Round` for rounded corners, and probably also `StrokeStartLineCap` and `StrokeEndLineCap` for rounded line ends:

```
<Path StrokeLineJoin="Round"
      StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
      StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
      ... />
```